# session_start(): open failed: Permission denied (13) (APACHE) after session_destroy() (logout)

Tags: php, apache

I know this question already exists here, but everything I found couldn't help me, so I'm asking this question again.

### Setup ##:

- Apache 2.4.52 win64 VS16
- PHP 8.1.2
- Win10

### Error message:

> Warning: session_start(): open(./../session\sess_7ou4verev1af2nvmvhionetk5j, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in F:\MyApp\web\src\dist\index.php on line 10
>
> Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path: ./../session) in F:\MyApp\web\src\dist\index.php on line 10**

### Login / Logout

I would like to give the user the possibility to log in and out. When the user has logged in, the username and user language are stored in `$_SESSION`. Nothing that would be complicated. I already implemented something similar a few years ago with **PHP 7.X**, currently I use **PHP 8**.

After logging in, I store the session ID in my Postgres database (user table). So I can always check if the user whose name is stored in `$_SESSION['username']` is logged in or not (anymore).

Session start in `index.php`.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

// - dist/ (directory root)
// - server/
// - session/

session_save_path('./../session'); 
session_id();
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start(); // line 10 where error appears
}
```

Logout (API). Can be triggered by user (typescript/javascript).

```
public static function logout()
    {
        // Unset all of the session variables.
        $_SESSION = array();
        if (\session_destroy() === true) {
            // Response that is send to the client
            return self::response(\CODE_SUCCESS, \API_LOGOUT_SUCCESS);
        } else {
            return self::response(\CODE_FAILED_SERVER_FAULT, \API_LOGOUT_FAILED);
        }
    }
```

Client logout.

```
Api.logout((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    Router.routeAuthentification(); // Redirect to login page
}, (error) => {
    if (error.statusText !== null) errorHandler.error(error.statusText);
});
```

```
static routeAuthentification() {
    const url = window.location;
    const protocol = url.protocol; 
    const hostname = url.hostname; 
    const port = url.port; 
    window.location.href = `${protocol}//${hostname}:${port}/auth`;
}
```

### More Information

When does the error appear? Whenever I log out via my API.

If I comment out the `routeAuthentification()` redirect and reload the page manually, the above error does not appear - instead, the server redirects me to the login page regularly (via `Index.php`).

If I use `window.reload()` instead of the redirect, however, the same error appears again.

I have already tried the following things:

- set `session_save_path`
- changed user and group in `httpd.conf`:

```
User _www
Group _www
```

#### Router class

```
class Router {
    static route(pathName: string) {
        const url = window.location;
        const protocol = url.protocol; 
        const hostname = url.hostname; 
        const port = url.port; 
        window.location.href = `${protocol}//${hostname}:${port}${pathName}`;
    }

    static reload() {
        location.reload();
    }

    static routeRoot() {
        this.route('/');
    }

    static routeAuthentification() {
        this.route('/auth');
    }

    static routeHelp() {
        this.route('/help');
    }

}

export {
    Router
}
```

Comment: can you show us Router.routeAuthentification() function?

Comment: Added router class to my question.